# Community Server the new version do you recommend it? can you integrate new modules to it?

Tags: asp.net, community-server, telligent

I am planning to use community sever for one of our projects, i used it in the past but we had a lot of problems customizing it and understanding how things work, im affraid to get into that again, and i would like to add some things to it but i dont know how flexible it is.

Answer (score 3):

Based on the fact we've been working with CS ever since version 1.0 (and even before as ASP.Net Forums) I can tell you this - CS 2007 and 2008 introduces a great out-of-the-box community solution along with a very extensive platform you can develop on top of and extend.

If you're aiming at Microsoft technologies this is the place to be.

IMPORTANT - Don't rush into their SDK and start changing the moving parts, focus on learning their theming engine (Chameleon) and using it's large variety of controls that get you farther than you could imagine. Use the SDK only when you need a better understanding of the inner working of things and when you've reached the point of extending CS.

IMPORTANT #2 - When extending, remember that Telligent releases two major versions every year, usually including features you'd want for your project, remember to review your changes and develop outside of the product core for easier upgrade to future versions.

Good luck!